# Does shopify allows partial refund on orders?

Tags: api, shopify

Can we do partial refund on orders without cancelling the order in shopify?

And also i tried to partially refund an order on cancellation, but no where in that `Orders` API call i found the refunded amount.
So is there any way i can get the partially refunded amount in API calls.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an order amount has been captured the authorization can no longer be used for making any changes (i.e. refunds)

The workaround would be either issue a refund through the payment processor (i.e. paypal) or by issuing the customer a flat amount discount code.